# Not Geting Subtotal in a template in model folder in Magento

Tags: magento

I am working on a custom module in magento and i want to get a subtotal form cart for that i am using following code.
    echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); 
But it return 0(zero) when i execute the page.
Please can anyone help me regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
$subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response.But when i use this code it give an error on fornt-end. where i am wrong..?

Comment: $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
$subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue(); This code work on localhost very well but not on server. can any one tell me why please?